# only one button works in react js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I was building a website using React. It's supposed that there are products that can be added to the cart by clicking "Add to Cart" button.

For now, I am just trying to access each "Add to Cart" button by console logging "action" in the reducer, but only one button among all of them can be triggered.

**Code for Product**

```
import {useStateValue} from "./StateProvider"

function Product({id, title, image, price, rating}) {
    //accepts props of each product
    
    const [state, dispatch] = useStateValue()

    const addToCart = () => {
        dispatch({
            type: "ADD_TO_CART",
            item: {
                id: id,
                title: title,
                image: image,
                price: price,
                rating: rating
            }
        }) 
    }

  return ( 
    <div className='product'>
        <div className="product-info">
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p className="product-price">
                <small>$</small>
                <strong>{price}</strong>
            </p>
            <div className="product-rating">
                {Array(rating)
                    .fill()
                    .map((_, i) => (
                        <p></p>
                    ))}
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <img 
            src={image}
            alt=""
        />

        <button onClick={addToCart}>Add to cart</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Code for StateProvider**

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer} from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children}) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

**Code for Reducer I was using**

```
export const initialState = {
    cart: [],
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            return{
                ...state,
                cart: [...state.cart, action.item]
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

There are 6 products in total ibn my website and none of them except for the last one fires `console.log(action)` when clicked.

In the main index file, I used this code to import the reducer

```
import reducer, { initialState } from './reducer';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
      <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I tried to add a unique value to each product, to correct the z-index but nothing changed. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in **CSS file** , I wasn't quite attentive :(
there was **another div with z-index** and it was set to **minus one** ( I didn't notice minus sign ). This div caused an overlay covering buttons that's why they didn't work
If you have **the same problem** , check your **styling file** very carefully , especially **divs** and **z-index** everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

i think it should be like this:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initialState);
```